# Delegate 'System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not take 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task myTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestMethodRefresh());
myTask.ContinueWith(() => TestMethodPrint(null), System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);

private void TestMethodPrint(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) {
            testDiv.InnerHtml = "from continue with";

}
```

I am trying to use code that works fine in .net framework 4.0 vb.net but i am unable to use it in asp.net .net framework 4.5. I am not sure what it means it does not take 0 arguments. I tried supplying additional arguments in the lamba but it just says it does not take those additional number of arguments either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler tells you about the error, because you call .ContinueWith and give it a delegate, that accepts 0 arguments, while .ContinueWith expects `Action<Task>` not `Action`. To solve your problem change the code as following:

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestMethodRefresh());
myTask.ContinueWith((t) => TestMethodPrint(null), new CancellationToken());
```

Other overload can look like this:

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });
myTask.ContinueWith((s, o) => TestMethodPrint(null), new object(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The parameter (t) you are receiving in ContinueWith is previous task. Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to learn more.

Comment: I tried this while passing a taskscheduler instead of a cancellationtoken and i get the same error.

Comment: You can't do it like this. I've used overload which receive Action<Task> and CancellationToken. If you want to pass TaskScheduler check this overload and supply all required params. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194761%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I've updated my post, to use that other overload, so code would simply compile. But you really need to understand the signature and what params you are passing.